# Document execCommand doest work as expected

Tags: javascript

im trying to highlight multiple sentences in HTML text using :

`document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, color);`

but the problem is when i highlight a second sentence which is next to the previous execCommand wraps both of them inside the same span.
Why is this happening and what can be the solution.

Comment: According to Mozilla: `document.execCommand`  is no longer recommended. Try to find an alternative solution. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: i see, thank you. But what alternatives can i use.

Comment: Use CSS `::selection` have a look at: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/